# How do I get a Canvas object's ID so I can delete it in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm just learning some tkinter, just trying to get the feel of it.

In my simple window is a canvas in a frame. There is an input field. Write some text, click the button and the text will appear below the button.

There are 4 labels in the canvas. I want to get the object ID of label4, so I can delete it each time around, then recreate label4. Otherwise, the new text is on top of the old text in label4.

Someone told me use:

> canvas1.delete("all")

but that deletes all labels and my button. (also tried canvas1.delete(label4) and canvas1.delete("label4") but didn't seem to work.)

I read that I need the object's ID to delete it, which is just an integer, so I guessed label4's ID would be 4. I set:

> canvas1.delete(4)

Which got rid of label4 the first time, before the function getInput() recreates it. But that only works 1 time. A new entry in the input field and a click of the button recreates label4, but the ID is no longer 4, because the second time around, label4's text stays.

**How do I get a canvas object's ID so that I can specifically delete that object?**

```
def myWindow1():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Get a text input and echo it")
    window.config(bg='light blue')
    window.geometry('640x480')
    # make a frame to take the canvas
    frame=Frame(window,width=400,height=300, bg='lightblue')
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH) #.grid(row=0,column=0)

    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, width=20, activebackground='red', )
    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, width=20, activebackground='green', )
    xscrollbar.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill = X )
    yscrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

    #canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(window, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set, bg='white', width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
    #canvas1.pack()
    canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(frame, bg='white', width = 400, height = 300,  relief = 'raised')
    canvas1.config(xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
    canvas1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    label1 = tkinter.Label(frame, text='Echo a text input')
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1)

    label2 = tkinter.Label(frame, text='Type your text:')
    label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

    entry1 = tkinter.Entry (frame) 
    canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

    def getInput():
        
        canvas1.delete(4)
        #label4.destroy
        msg = entry1.get()
        
        label3 = tkinter.Label(frame, text= 'You entered this text:',font=('helvetica', 10))
        canvas1.create_window(200, 210, window=label3)
        # wraplength is in pixels not characters!!
        #label4 = tkinter.Label(window, text=msg,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'), anchor='w', width=35, wraplength=80)
        #label4 = tkinter.Label(frame, text=msg,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'), anchor='w', width=55, wraplength=390)
        label4 = tkinter.Label(frame, text=msg,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'), anchor='w', wraplength=390)
        #canvas1.update()
        canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label4)
        # don't set the y value too high or you won't see the output!
        #canvas1.create_window(200, 320, window=label4)

    global label4
    label4 = tkinter.Label(frame, text= 'Your input will be here after you click the button.',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'), anchor='w', wraplength=390)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 250, window=label4)    
    button1 = tkinter.Button(text='Get the text message', command=getInput, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
    
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a Canvas object's ID so I can delete it in tkinter?

The identifier is returned when you create an object on the canvas:

```
the_id = canvas1.create_window(...)
...
canvas1.delete(the_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in an old thread here, but I did not understand it! Tinkering with tkinter is not easy! Is there any way to get the ID after the fact??

Comment: Well, I tried, but I can't make it work! Don't know what I am doing wrong. canvas1.delete('the_id') or canvas1.delete(the_id) or canvas1.delete("the_id") just cause and error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 34, in getInput
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2514, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression

Comment: @Pedroski: it needs to be `canvas1.delete(the_id)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to trouble you! The problem was me putting things in the wrong place! I've got it working now. Also, from other threads, I found I can put:  canvas1.create_window(... , tags="mylabel") then do: canvas1.delete("mylabel") One day I will get the hang of this! Thanks a lot!